# Python Syntax Error for no reason

Tags: python, syntax

I got the following function:

```
def infinite_count():
    a = 1
    while a <= int(reciever_runtime):
        send_message(float(reciever_sleeptime),a)
        print_stats()
    else:
        print ("All the messages have been sent")
```

Whenever I run my code I get the following error:

```
    send_message(float(reciever_sleeptime), message_to_send)
           ^ 
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's the code for the send_message() function:

```
def send_message(sleep_time, send_msg):
    #Entering the message
    #Setting path to the textbox
    message_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="composerInput"]""")
    #Typing the message
    message_textbox.send_keys(send_msg)

    #Sending the message
    #Setting path
    send_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="u_0_5"]""")
    #Clicking the button in order to send the message
    send_button.click()

    #Wait time before sending another message IN SECONDS!
    time.sleep( sleep_time )
```

What is going on? I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: I don't get any errors.  Are you sure that you provided all of the code necessary to reproduce?

Comment: Make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces. Use four spaces. Don't use tabs.

Comment: check your spaces, have you mixed up tabs and spaces ? I had same issue on pycharm though it was python 2.7 . so i converted all tabs into spaces. Give it a go

Comment: Oh crap, turns out I had a little space before the function definition. Works now, thank you guys! This really got on my nerves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code is working and this is all of the code needed to reproduce the error. The cause is how you indent your code as @ReutSharabani has said in the comments.

Comment: Yap, fixed it, I had a little space before the function definition.